# How to make linkable data from a query in a table

Tags: javascript, php

How can i make the data from my query linkable/clickable so that i can run a function when I click it. The data that needs to be linkable/clickable is the date and after clicking it will run a function.

Below is my code in PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['go'])){
    if (((!empty($_POST['from'])&&!empty($_POST['to'])))&&((!empty($_POST['from'])&&!empty($_POST['to'])))){
        $from = $_POST['from'];
        $to = $_POST['to'];
        $from =explode('/',$from);
        $from = "$from[2]-$from[0]-$from[1]";
        $to = explode ('/',$to);
        $to = "$to[2]-$to[0]-$to[1]";
        $query= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Date, Time, Latitude,Longitude,Depth,Magnitude 
                                   FROM bulletin WHERE Date between '$from' and '$to';");
        $the_array  = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $date = $row['Date'];
            $time = $row['Time'];
            $latitude= $row['Latitude'];
            $longitude= $row['Longitude'];
            $depth =$row['Depth'];
            $magnitude = $row['Magnitude'];
            $the_arraypei[] = array($row['Date'] ); //added
            echo '<tr class="normalRow">
                     <td onClick="document.location.href="http://www.yoursite.com";">'.$date.'</a></td>
                     <td border="1">'.$time.'</td>
                     <td border="1">'.$latitude.'</td>
                     <td border="1">'.$longitude.'</td>
                     <td border="1">'.$depth.'</td>
                     <td border="1">'.$magnitude.'</td>
                  </tr>';
        }
    $js_array1 =$the_arraypei;//added               
}
```

Comment: Where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: im stuck at making the Date result clickable, i want it to be like when i click any of the Date result  a function will run another query

Comment: You are missing the opening `<a>` in your first `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't opened up an anchor tag `<a>` within the td.

Also, avoid writing your HTML within the PHP echo statement.

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['go'])){
    /* Other code */
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      /* Loop statements... */ 
      $the_arraypei[] = array($row['Date'] ); 
?>
<tr class="normalRow">
    <td> 
       <a href="http://www.yoursite.com";"><?php echo $date; ?></a>
    </td>
    <td border="1"><?php echo $time ?> </td>
    <!-- Other tds.... -->
    <td border="1"><?php echo $magnitude; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php } 
   js_array1 = $the_arraypei; //added
 }
?>
```

Comment: hi @object how can i make the $date onclick? and able to run a function..and were can i place the code of the function outside the php code or inside the php code?thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to modify your code like that:

```
echo '<tr class="normalRow"><td><a href="http://www.google.it" target="_blank">'.$date.'</a></td><td border="1">'.$time.'</td><td border="1">'.$latitude.'</td><td border="1">'.$longitude.'</td><td border="1">'.$depth.'</td><td border="1">'.$magnitude.'</td></tr>';
```

If you want to open a new window without javascript. Otherwise if you want to execute a javascript function you can do:

```
echo '<tr class="normalRow"><td><button onClick="executeMe()">'.$date.'</button></td><td border="1">'.$time.'</td><td border="1">'.$latitude.'</td><td border="1">'.$longitude.'</td><td border="1">'.$depth.'</td><td border="1">'.$magnitude.'</td></tr>';
```

And on page you should add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function executeMe() {
        console.log('Hello World!');
    }
</script>
```

Try it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick)

Comment: hi @stuzzo beside making it a button how can i make the $date to be onClick??